# Как обрабатывать нажатия кнопки kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как обрабатывать нажатия на кнопку в kivyMD пытался написать on_press(PressButton) но ошибка!

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder 
 
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
 
KV = """ 
MDScreen: 
 
 FitImage: 
 source: 'BackGround.jpg' 
 
 MDRaisedButton: 
 text: "Patch" 
 pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1} 
 MDIconButton: 
 icon: "youtube.jpg" 
 pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} 
""" 
 
 
class MainnApp(MDApp): 
 def build(self): 
 self.root = Builder.load_string(KV) 
 
 def PressButton(self): 
  print("Button is press") 
 
MainnApp().run()
```

Comment: хоть код свой прикрепи

Comment: from kivy.lang import Builder 
 
from kivymd.app import MDApp 
 
KV = """ 
MDScreen: 
 
 FitImage: 
 source: 'BackGround.jpg' 
 
 MDRaisedButton: 
 text: "Patch" 
 pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1} 
 MDIconButton: 
 icon: "youtube.jpg" 
 pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} 
""" 
 
 
class MainnApp(MDApp): 
 def build(self): 
 self.root = Builder.load_string(KV) 
 
 def PressButton(self): 
  print("Button is press") 
 
MainnApp().run()

Comment: а из обычного киви нажатие не работает ?def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print(touch.x,touch.y)       
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)

Comment: Не получилось, но вот так он выводит в консоль текст но как обратится именно к функции MDIconButton: 
 icon: "youtube.jpg" 
 pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5} 
 on_press: print("ouch! More gently please")